# Swipe to navigate back in iOS is not functioning with PopScope

Tags: flutter

I have a welcome screen, and I want to prevent the user from navigating back to the previous screen (which is the splash screen in my case).

Below is my code snippet of PopScope. It works fine on Android, but on iOS, swipe navigation to go back isn't functioning as expected. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this issue. Thank you.

```
return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold());
```

Comment: Why do you need to make swipe navigation on iOS working if you wan to prevent users from navigating back to the previous screen?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prevent the user from navigating back to splashScreen just use

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourScreen()));
```

or

```
 Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/yourscreen');
```

in your splashScreen code it will replace your current splashScreen, and remove PopScope in your welcome screen it is not needed now.

checkout [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jaimin. I am not looking for the alternative, i just want to know using PopScope, because by using the WillPopScope we can do this but it is not working in PopScope.